# Starting Apache service “requested operation has failed”

Tags: apache-2.2

Whenever I try to start apache server on my local development computer I get prompted an error message as follows:

```
The requested operation has failed
```

httpd.conf was not tampered with. How do I set it up to work?

Comment: Do you see anything helpful in /var/log/httpd/error_log?

Comment: I don't have that directory (var) inside my Apache installation.

Comment: I lold at this ^

Answer (score 7):

This is usually caused by one of two problems:

1. You already have something running on Port 80. It's most common that your development box has IIS installed on it, and IIS is using port 80. You can solve this issue by any of:

   - stopping the IIS service ("World Wide Web Publishing Service")
   - changing the binding on the IIS site
   - uninstall IIS (or remove the Feature in Vista/2008 or newer OSes)
2. The Apache service is disabled. Open `services.msc` and check the Apache service, make sure it's not disabled. It should be set to Manual or Automatic start-up, depending on your environment.

Comment: For example Skype reserves (for wtf reason) port 80. If you are running Skype on your machine, try to turn it off, start Apache and then turn Skype back on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the path in `services.msc` relating to Apache (default is `Apache2.2` I think) to see if it matches path to your `httpd.exe`.

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Where did you see that invisible tag about Windows? :)

Comment: That's a Windows service error. This is likely an WAMP stack or similar.

Answer (score 1):

if apache is not starting and getting error "Requested operation failed"

go to the command prompt : services.msc
search for Apache> right click and select properties.
In the General tab one startup type drop down is there. Change it to Automatic and click Apply.
Then Start button will get enabled.

Comment: What operating system is this? It might not match what OP has...

Comment: This is Windows.